# how to run nodemon in windows from package.json

Tags: nodemon, invalid-characters, npm-start

I'm following a [VUE tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI&t=21m43s) on a mac (shown in youtube).

In my `src/app.js` I have only `console.log('hi');`

The start command for the Mac in `package.json` as shown on the youtube video is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
```

},

In which case the nodemon was not found.

So I changed the forward slashes to backslashes thus:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": ".\\node_modules\\nodemon\\bin\\nodemon.js src\\app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "lint": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\eslint **\\*.js"
```

},

but now when I run `npm start` I get an alert with error in nodemon.js

```
 line 1 
 charachter 1
 invalid character
 800A03F6
```

I tried with a forward slash in the src/app.js  and got the same error. Is it something to do with the single quotemark?

The tutorial is here: (start command seen at 21:43) here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI&t=21m43s

Comment: this question is good for any app using nodemon: VUE, React, and the likes of those.

Answer (score 12):

you just have to use

`npx nodemon app.js` command

after installing nodemon globaly 
with

`npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: When I run that on the command line, how come I keep spawning two node processes?  It only does this when I launch my app via npm or npx. One just calls "node" referencing nodemon.js and my app.js as parameters, and then another calls node.exe with my original app.js path as it's parameter

Answer (score 9):

## Solved!

OK, the solution was to install nodemon globally

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

And then changing the start string to

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'node && lint'"
```

Without it, running nodemon.js directly, even when I was inside the `bin` folder, was giving that error.

Nodemon version was and still is: 1.18.4 in both the local and global install.

Also, I had to change the single quotes in the --exec to escaped double quotes.

Instead of: `"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run node && lint'"`
I now have: `"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec \"npm run node && lint\""`

## The problem:

Calling the .js was the problem.

There is a `nodemon.cmd` command, in the `users\<myuser>\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder, which is in the windows 10 environment %PATH%.

There probably was a `nodemon.cmd` that I could call when installed locally. But don't ask me where that is.